# Java RMI - registering client on server side

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I am quite new to Java RMI. I have read the Sun tutorials as well as some info in a book about distributed systems.
Yet, I am quite confused about the task of the server. Although the server is supposed to be easy to design, I don't really get the grisp.
My remote interface provides me with the function:

```
public void login(String name, RemoteInterfaceClient client) throws RemoteException
```

How should I implement this in the Server class? I don't need obviously to do any checks, or?
thank you!

Comment: You aren't asking about RMI, you are asking what your own login method should do in your own system. Nobody can answer that for you. Not a real question.

Comment: You aren't by any chance swiss? (because of the `, or?`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a class that implements your interface and extends `UnicastRemoteObject`. In this way, when you call login method remotely, it will do your work.

Comment: So the method itself will have no body? I just put it in the Server class and that's it?

Comment: your remote interface will have login method and you will implement it in another class as I've mentioned. Interface obviously does not have method body

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite get it. You tell that i will implement it in another class (that would be actually my Server class that implements my remote interface). My problem is exactly this: I don't know how to implement it. I even get an error when I want to extend the UnicastRemoteObject

Comment: This would be my server class:    public class ServerClass implements ServerRemoteInterface

Comment: You will need to write a Java interface that declares the `login` method but does not define it. Then implement that interface in a class by defining the `login` method. That class must `extend UnicastRemoteObject` to be exported to an RMI registry that the remote machine will use to load the interface stub to call the `login`.

Comment: ok, a last question: how would the definition of the login method would look like? Thank you both!

Comment: This is about all about your design. Probably, you will do some checks, maybe some database work. You can write whatever you want in the method definiton